# In rxjs, how do I get the last value from a switchMap that is ended by takeUntil?

Tags: rxjs

Here is a typical rxjs example of drag-and-drop:

```
const drag$ = mousedown$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    (start) => {
      return mousemove$.pipe(map(move => {
        move.preventDefault();
        return {
          left: move.clientX - start.offsetX,
          top: move.clientY - start.offsetY
        }
      }),
        takeUntil(mouseup$));
    }));

drag$.subscribe(pos => {
  box.style.top = `${pos.top}px`
  box.style.left = `${pos.left}px`
});
```

The `takeUntil` will unsubscribe the inner observable of mouseMove$.  But what if I need the last value in the inner observable in order to do something with it upon the mouseUp?  I know I can probably assign a value to a global temporary variable to get at it that way but I'm trying to avoid that.

The more involved story of what I'm trying to do is this:

I'm working on a 3D game where I want to implement grab-and-throw.  I've set it up similar to the rxjs conanical drag-and-drop scenario where I'm subscribing to a controller 'squeeze' event, then `switchMap`ing to another observable of controller movement where I 'drag' and reposition the object where ever my hand position is, and finally I `takeUntil` the 'squeeze' is released, which lets go of the object.

But there is one more piece I need to implement for 'throwing' the object, which is I need the velocity vector of my hand movement at the moment the squeeze is released to apply an impulse force to the object so it flies away when I let go.  That vector can be calculated on every frame inside the `switchMap`'s `pipe` using `scan`.

The problem is `takeUntil` just stops the data stream and I don't have access the last value that was in the accumulator of `scan`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`withLatestFrom()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) operator to get the most recent emission from another observable.  The result is an array of the stream value, followed by the other observable's last emission:

[image: sample shape]

```
mouseup$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(drag$)
).subscribe(
  ([mouseup, drag]) => console.log({drag, mouseup})
);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66091794?file=index.ts) example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting problem, I'm guessing you also need the values as the `drag` event takes place, but also its last emitted value before the `mouseup` event occurs.

One approach I think would be this:

```js
const drag$ = mousedown$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    (start) => {
      mousemove$ = mousemove$.pipe(
        map(move => {
          move.preventDefault();
          return {
            left: move.clientX - start.offsetX,
            top: move.clientY - start.offsetY
          }
        }),
        takeUntil(mouseup$),
        share(),
      );

      return concat(
        // get the `mousemove` events as they take place
        mousemove$,

        mousemove$.pipe(
          reduce((acc, crt) => { /* ... */ }),
        ),
      )
}));
```

The `reduce` operator works the same as `scan`, with the exception that the former will emit the accumulated value when the source completes.

If you want to use the same `scan` logic in both observables, then the `switchMap`'s inner observable could look like this:

```js
mousemove$ = mousemove$.pipe(
  map(move => {
    move.preventDefault();
    return {
      left: move.clientX - start.offsetX,
      top: move.clientY - start.offsetY
    }
  }),
  scan((acc, crt) => { /* ... */ }),
  takeUntil(mouseup$),
  share(),
);

return concat(
  mousemove$,

  mousemove$.pipe(
    // it will emit the last emitted value when the source completes
    takeLast(1),
  ),
)
```